# do_rootfs: Can't install packagegroup-core-x11-utils-1.0-r40@all: no package provides xserver-nodm-init

Tags: yocto, bitbake

**At first I run the command to see my layers:**

```
$bitbake-layers show-layers
layer                 path                                  priority
meta                  .../poky-krogoth-15.0.0/meta             5
meta-poky             .../poky-krogoth-15.0.0/meta-poky        5
meta-yocto-bsp        .../poky-krogoth-15.0.0/meta-yocto-bsp   5
meta-oe               .../meta-openembedded/meta-oe            6
```

**and build my image:**

```
bitbake core-image-sato
```

**everything is OK,I found the meta-oe layer is useless. So I delete it:**

```
bitbake-layers remove-layer .../meta-openembedded/meta-oe
```

**and build it again:**

```
$bitbake core-image-sato
```

**it show error:**

> ERROR: core-image-sato-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Unable to install packages.
>
> Command
>   '/buildarea/ddu/poky-krogoth-15.0.0/build-beaglebone/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/smart
>   --log-level=warning --data-dir=/buildarea/ddu/poky-krogoth-15.0.0/build-beaglebone/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-sato/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/lib/smart
>   install -y packagegroup-core-ssh-dropbear@all
>   packagegroup-core-x11-sato-games@beaglebone
>   packagegroup-core-x11-base@all smartpm@cortexa8hf_neon
>   psplash@cortexa8hf_neon packagegroup-core-boot@beaglebone
>   packagegroup-base-extended@beaglebone rpm@cortexa8hf_neon
>   packagegroup-core-x11-sato@beaglebone
>   locale-base-en-us@cortexa8hf_neon locale-base-en-gb@cortexa8hf_neon'
>   returned 1:
>
> Loading cache... 
>   Updating cache...
>
> ################################## [100%]
>
> Computing transaction...error: Can't install
>   packagegroup-core-x11-utils-1.0-r40@all: no package provides
>   xserver-nodm-init
>
> ERROR: core-image-sato-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
>   ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
>   /buildarea/ddu/poky-krogoth-15.0.0/build-beaglebone/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-sato/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.52174
>   ERROR: Task 9
>   (/buildarea/ddu/poky-krogoth-15.0.0/meta/recipes-sato/images/core-image-sato.bb,
>   do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'

**Why it said that no package provides xserver-nodm-init?**

```
$find ../meta -name xserver-nodm-init*
../meta/recipes-graphics/x11-common/xserver-nodm-init.bb
../meta/recipes-graphics/x11-common/xserver-nodm-init
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. Why do you think meta-oe is useless?

And why do you want to delete it? It does no harm?

The general  rule is. If it does not break, Do not fix it. 
Like you said. Put everything back and it will work.

Comment: At the begining, I want to install some packages to my image, those packages depend on the meta-oe layer, so I add the layer to my bblayers.conf. At last I found I didn't use those packages, so I delete the meta-oe layer and rebuild the image, the build system throw the error.

Comment: Core image Sato depends on it

Comment: Yes, in yocto build a sato image need three layers: meta, meta-poky, meta-yocto-bsp

Comment: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-oe/ . Ctrl+F and find `xserver-nodm-init`, which is what he is missing.

Comment: Thank you very much, the meta layer also provide the xserver-nodm-init recipe, when I remove the meta-oe, why it not use that recipe under the meta layer?    [meta layer](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/openembedded-core/)

Comment: one of the possible reason is that you did not clean the build.  so it is still using the previous build, which is version 2.0. another reason is that you might specifically call it to use version 2.0 instead.

Comment: Ok, under you analysis, I sloved it by running: `bitbake xserver-nodm-init -ccleansstate && bitbake xserver-nodm-init` thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way meta-oe currently replaces some of the X11 startup components, you pretty much need to delete TMPDIR if you've build X11 with meta-oe in your bblayers.conf and then decide you want to remove meta-oe (as you have done). However, if you now just delete TMPDIR but *not* your sstate-cache and then try again then it'll restore everything back to where you were from sstate pretty quickly without needing to recompile everything, and the issue should be resolved.

What meta-oe is doing isn't desirable, there is a bug open to fix it:

https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5546

It's assigned to me and I'm sad to say I haven't had time to resolve it so far; it doesn't appear to be a priority for anyone else either.